# A question about the paper "Ensembling Ten Math Information Retrieval Systems"

Tags: information-retrieval

My question is about the paper [Ensembling Ten Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2936/paper-06.pdf).

I am interested in the task of finding answers.

Which of the ten system are able to answer questions using **only** dot products?

(I think CompuBERT is one of them, [look](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT/blob/master/sentence-transformers/sentence_transformers/question_responder.py))

Comment: We have collected some advice on selecting a good itle [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Please take some time to improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All ten systems are able to retrieve answers using only the dot product:

- All eight MSM systems (MG, PZ, MH, LM, MP, JK, AM, and VS) use [the standard vector space model (VSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) with either the BM25 or TF-IDF weighting. The document similarity measure in the VSM can be computed as a *sparse* dot product for a pair of documents and as a *sparse* matrix product for a pair of corpora.
- The MIRMU – SCM system uses [the soft vector space model (soft VSM)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09407v1). The document similarity measure in the soft VSM can also be computed as a *sparse* dot product for a pair of documents, see [Theorem 4.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09407v1.pdf#page=3), although [our implementation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fe8e2042f0c8c16abc502220f5a4f88c72d2b31d/gensim/similarities/termsim.py#L580) uses the following formula: $x^T\cdot S\cdot y.$
- The MIRMU – CompuBERT system produces 768-dimensional document embeddings. The document similarity measure is the *dense* dot product, see [method `TrainedIRSystem.search()` in file `eval_arqmath.py`](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bxYwWzDX3z81S4TwUaTvqZBHtiMOngez). Note that [your link in the original post](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT) points to an outdated version of the system used in ARQMath 2020.

Comment: If ALL systems use SPARSE algorithms why are all systems so slow (as for ME they are slow...)? Where is the bottleneck of the algorithms? Does the bottleneck have the same origin in all algorithms? (Is it better to post another question for answering this commnet @Witiko?)

Comment: let me make the first phrase more precise: Instead of reading "If ALL systems..." read "If ALL systems using VSM and soft VSM".

Comment: The short answer is: "Because the systems have been optimized for correctness, not for speed. They are experimental prototypes, not industry-strength systems." However, that is not a very good answer, is it? If you update the original question, I will update my answer with some details about why the systems are so slow and how they can be sped up.

Comment: I don't know well the rules of stackexchange but I think it is better to post another question. So look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144264/how-can-i-optimize-the-systems-in-the-paper-ensembling-ten-math-information-ret)