# How can I optimize the systems in the paper "Ensembling Ten Math Information Retrieval Systems"

Tags: algorithm-analysis

My question is about the paper [Ensembling Ten Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2936/paper-06.pdf).

I already know the algorithms in the paper can answer questions only using dot products (look the [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144236/a-question-about-the-paper-ensembling-ten-math-information-retrieval-systemshttps://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144236/a-question-about-the-paper-ensembling-ten-math-information-retrieval-systems)).

How can I optimize them?

Could you add here (and in the next paper you will produce) the complexities of time preprocessing, memory and time consumption for question answering for all systems? (this is a solicitation for @Witiko)

Comment: Please define what you mean by "optimize them".   Note that we don't accept questions directed at specific individuals.  Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @D.W. It may be a good idea to merge this question with [the previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/144247/12931) of the poster, which asks about a property of the information retrieval systems (do they use a dot product?) that only has a vague connection to the real question.

Comment: @Witiko, thanks.  This looks like a different question to me.

Comment: I suppose it may be marginally useful to practicioners studying the implementation of information retrieval systems to consider the original question in isolation, although it displays [the classic XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/342119).

Comment: @R. S. Can you share a little about your background and aims? It would be easier to answer your questions if we knew what you were trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: I have an idea (different from the algorithms cited below) to greatly speed-up at least the system CompuBERT and I wouldn't like to waste time studying and trying to understand all the 10 systems... I will share my aims later... For the moment you are answering what I need @Witiko.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two major ways in which you can make the ten math information retrieval systems in [the MIRMU and MSM at ARQMath 2021 paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2936/paper-06.pdf) (and many other experimental retrieval systems) faster:

1. using appropriate data structures for [exact nearest-neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Exact_methods),
2. using [approximate nearest-neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximation_methods).

##### Data structures

All systems except MSM – PZ use either sparse or dense matrices to represent the document corpus and to perform exact NNS. For a corpus of size $n$, this is a representation that is easy to construct ($\mathcal{O(n)}$), but quite costly for nearest-neighbor search (NNS) even if we bound the query length by a constant because we need to check every document in the collection ($\mathcal{O}(n)$) even if we only need the 1,000 nearest neighbors or fewer.

MSM – PZ uses [pyserini](https://github.com/castorini/pyserini), which is a Python library on top of the industry-strength Apache Lucene. Lucene uses [the inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) to represent a document corpus. For a corpus of size $n$, the worst-case time complexity of NNS is still $\mathcal{O}(n)$, but since we will only check documents that contain at least one term from the query, the actual speed is much higher. You can see this in the speed results from the paper, where MSM – PZ is much faster at searching (1.1 seconds per a query on average) than the other systems:

[image: Average query time and the training and preprocessing of the individual systems (log scale).]

All systems except MSM – PZ that use NNS with sparse high-dimensional vectors (i.e. all except MSM – PZ and MIRMU – CompuBERT) can be optimized by using an inverted index instead of matrices as their data structure. For MIRMU – CompuBERT, we could use any data structure for NNS with dense low-dimensional vectors, which [there are several](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms).

##### Approximate nearest-neighbor search

Moving away from exact search allows you to achieve $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time complexity of NNS with dense low-dimensional vectors at the cost of accuracy: some nearest neighbors may be missed and some distant neighbors may show up at the family dinner. Embarassing! Popular algorithms implemented in Python include [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) and [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). The MIRMU – CompuBERT system could be optimized this way.

Since the constant-time complexity depends on a constant number of dimensions, the above does not apply to sparse high-dimensional vectors, where the dimensionality is not constant but equals the vocabulary size ($\sqrt{n}$ according to [Heaps' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaps%27_law)). [The curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) rears its ugly head once again! Here are some tentative ideas for a solution:

1. You could use [dimensionality reduction techniques](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition) to reduce high-dimensional sparse vectors to low-dimensional dense vectors. However, there are reasons to believe that [this will impact your retrieval performance](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1964897.1964900).
2. Alternatively, you can achieve $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time complexity in an inverted index by pre-sorting documents by a common criterion that reflects general usefulness (e.g. [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)) and then stop the retrieval after a certain number of documents has been collected. See [the textbook of Manning](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/computing-scores-in-a-complete-search-system-1.html) for a more complete discussion and implementation details. In theory, [pyserini](https://github.com/castorini/pyserini) should be capable of this, but I am not sufficiently familiar with it.

##### Why is MIRMU – SCM so slow?

It is, isn't it? 3.72 minutes per a query on average. The SCM uses the formula $\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y}$ to compute the similarity of two documents $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ according to a term similarity matrix $S$:

[image: The representation of two documents, “Hi, world” and “Hello, world” in the TF-IDF vector space model (VSM, left) and in the TF-IDF soft vector space model (soft VSM, right).]

*The representation of two documents, “Hi, world” $(\vec{x})$ and “Hello, world” $(\vec{y})$ in the TF-IDF vector space model (VSM, left) and in the TF-IDF soft vector space model (soft VSM, right). In the VSM, different terms correspond to orthogonal axes, making the document representations distant despite their semantic equivalence. In the soft VSM, different terms correspond to non-orthogonal axes, where the angle between the axes is proportional to the similarity $(S)$ of terms in a word embedding space (middle).*

This formula [is quadratic in the vocabulary size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Soft_cosine_measure) ($\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})^2 = \mathcal{O}(n)$ according to [Heaps' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaps%27_law)), which makes NNS extremely costly ($n\cdot \mathcal{O}(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$). However, as I show in proof to Theorem 3.4 in [my paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09407), we can reduce the time complexity from $\mathcal{O}(n)$ to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ by making sure that matrix $S$ contains no more than $C$ non-zero elements in any column for a constant $C$ (we used $C = 100$ in MIRMU – SCM). [Here is our implementation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fe8e2042f0c8c16abc502220f5a4f88c72d2b31d/gensim/similarities/termsim.py#L580) in the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) Python library. It is painfully slow. Why?

The paper assumes that we will compute $\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y}$ as a single operation, which will allow us to eliminate any $i$ and $j$ for which either $x_i = 0, y_i = 0,$ or $s_{ij} = 0$: $$\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y} = \sum_i\sum_j x_i\cdot s_{ij}\cdot y_j$$ [Our implementation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fe8e2042f0c8c16abc502220f5a4f88c72d2b31d/gensim/similarities/termsim.py#L580) uses the SciPy library for convenience. SciPy will separate $\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y}$ into two operations: $\vec{x}^T\cdot S$ and $\_\cdot\vec{y}$. This makes our implementation $O(\sqrt{n})$ instead of $O(1)$.

Here are some ideas for an improvement:

1. If you can figure out how to compute $\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y}$ over sparse high-dimensional $\vec{x}, \vec{y},$ and $S$ efficiently in Python, you could significantly speed up MIRMU – SCM. This may involve low-level Cython or C programming.
2. Alternatively, you could use the transformations discussed in Theorem 4.2 of my paper to first transform the document vectors to a form $\vec{x}', \vec{y}',$ where a simple dot product $\vec{x}'^T\cdot\vec{y}'$ is equivalent to $\vec{x}^T\cdot S\cdot\vec{y}$, and then use some general solution for exact or approximate NNS over sparse high-dimensional vectors as discussed in the first part of my answer.

Neither is a simple undertaking and will require significant programming expertise and effort. Perhaps you can contribute?

Comment: Let me comment the nearest neighbor algorithms cited in the answer:

Comment: [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) uses random projections (which means Annoy does not learn the bits from data - learning strategies are better...) which has low recall if you want to perform fast queries (as for me Annoy is very slow). (moreover, in [github](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) it is written Annoy does not perform well on high dimensional spaces and textual data are high dimensional).

Comment: [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) is one of the fastest and less memory consuming algorithm working on a billion scale but uses GPUs (as for me GPUs are expensive so useless). I have found a better algorithm with similar memory and time performance as Faiss but work on CPUs so it is better than Faiss. (I will not tell here the name of the algorithm now and I will explain why not later...)

Comment: "Perhaps you can contribute?" Yes, I want to contribute. If I decide to write a paper, can we work together? @Witiko Are you an open-minded prone to work together with an unkown person which you have only talked on internet an lives in another continent? (I am asking this because I have already emailed other people inviting them to collaborate together but they never answered...)

Comment: At the moment, I am writing my dissertation and therefore quite busy. But please, send me an e-mail specifying the research questions and the target venue of the paper, and we can talk.

Comment: "Annoy does not perform well on high dimensional spaces and textual data are high dimensional)." Indeed. I listed annoy and faiss as dense low-dimensional vector databases. There seem to be far fewer high-dimensional sparse vector databases.